# navigation doesn't come back to view after resizing browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have navigation hidden for mobile screen and instead hamburger menu icon. When I click the icon, navigation list comes to view and when I click again it disappears. (jquery slideToggle effect). For desktop view it's just an inline navigation. Problem is that when I resize the window, navigation appears and disappears on different breakpoints, but once I click on hamburger icon when screen is less than 450px and resize it do desktop size again, the inline navigation doesn't show up. What's the problem? Does it has anything to do with jquery? Maybe it hiddens navigation list items once I click hamburger icon again and it prevents it from coming back to view on deskop view?

Code:

```js
$(document).ready (function () {
  $(".arrow").click(function () {
    $(".expand").slideToggle(600);
  });

  $(".hamburger").click(function () {
    $("nav").slideToggle(600);
    $("nav ul li").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  z-index: 5;
}

nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}



}

@media screen and (min-width: 451px) {
  nav {
    display: inline;
  }

  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-grid">
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-3">
      <p class="logo"><a href="index.html">LOGO</a></p>
      <img class="hamburger" src="images/hamburger.svg" width="9%">
      <img class="arrow" src="images/arrow.svg" width="20px">
      <div class="expand">
        <ul>
          <li>EN</li>
          <li>DK</li>
          <li>NO</li>
          <li>SE</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-9">
    
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">REFERENCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Uhm... in the code above, you have `nav` set to `display: none;` - and nowhere do you set that as `display: block;` - The whole design, also the use of the jQuery for displaying the menu is mostly completely useless, and should be rewritten. There is no reason to use any javascript for the things you're doing. Also, you should write the menu-items with regular text (not all-caps), and just do `text-transform: uppercase;` - that way it's easy to redesign the menu later, if needed.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie  It's a display:none for mobile screen and for desktop it's display:inline. And why is jquery useless?